# How to implement "Back" conversation in Chatbot

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot

I wish to implement following scenario conversation in MS botframework

```
Bot: =>  what can do for you?            => User
Bot: <=  I want to rent a house         <= User
Bot: =>  Which city?                    => User
Bot: <=                 London          <= User
Bot: =>  How many bedrooms              => User
Bot: <=  Ops, I want a home in New York <= User  #User wish to change the topic here..
```

In MS botframework, how can I use Waterfall dialog to implement above story? any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to implement it with waterfall approach with reasonable efforts. In simple case you can try to analyze the response, in your case it is a number of bedrooms, and if it is not a number, you can check the response for another request. The problem here is that you should do it for all responses and for open text responses it will be hard to distinguish between a legal answer or a topic change.

So, you should implement it using an intent approach.

First, you need an intent detector, you can use Luis as it is highly integrated with the bot framework or implement your own intent detector.

In in you case, this detector should detect the intent - `I want to rent a house` (a car and so on).

```
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [luis] });
```

See https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/IntentDialog
These code examples are for Node.Js but the same approach should works for .Net.

Then, for each intent you should register an appropriate action that starts an  waterfall dialog that gets all necessary data.

```
bot.beginDialogAction("RentHouseAction", RentHouseDialog.name+":/", { matches: "RentHouseAction"});
```

where RentHouseAction is the action you define in Luis
RentHouseDialog is a waterfall dialog that is reside in the library.

```
bot.library(RentHouseDialog);
```

Note that as the RentHouseDialog dialog finishes it will return to the place where the previous dialog has stopped. So, it again asks - `How many bedrooms`.
To prevent this behavior you should detect that your previous dialog hasn't finished yet (you can use the state for it where you collect the answers) and call `session.replaceDialog('<>');`.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Sergey, thanks for your reply, it's really helpful.but if the reply from is " oops, not London, New york, please! " so it's difficult to direct an RentHouse intent, for human being, it's very clear, the end user wish to rent a house in New york based on context,  in my bot code, How can I achieve this? thanks in advance

Comment: @YuhuaDeng that would be a `changeLocation` intent.

Comment: @stuartd, you mean Luis can recognize  " oops, not London, New york, please! " as a changeLocation? ,oh, let me try it, I will feedback soon...

Comment: At the current state of AI, you cannot implement a bot that is as smart as a human. So, Luis can  understand - `Ops, I want a home in New York` as a wish to rent a house but not `oops, not London, New York please!` (probably a comment from @stuartd may help). But your bot should be ready that it cannot understand a reply. In case of `oops, not London..` it should say - `Sorry, I don't understand you. Would you like to: 1) change the location, 2) cancel a request, 3) display the help and so on.

Comment: @Sergey it is possible for Luis to recognise that kind of intent, but it needs to be specifically trained to do so.

Comment: @SergeyL, your solution works for me, thanks a lot, let me mark your answer as solution.